# String slicing not working for accented characters

Tags: python, string

String slicing in Python 2.7 is very useful to get a substring. This works nicely for ASCII characters, for example

```
>>> s = "Antonio"
>>> s[5:7]
'io'
```

but fails in the presence of accented characters, for example

```
>>> s = "António"
>>> s[5:7]
'ni'
```

What is the safe way to get the correct substring irrespective of the characters present in the original string?

**UPDATE** My configuration info is the following:

```
Python 2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 12:54:16) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

Thanks

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue in Python 2.7.9. `"António"[5:7]` gives `"io"`

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? Also, to do this properly and understand the solution, you may need to read up on exactly what a "character" is. The [Unicode FAQ](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html) may be a good starting point, particularly ["How are characters counted..."](http://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html#7).

Comment: @user2357112 Nice link. But what is the Python 2.7.11 API for counting the characters correctly and get the right substring? Note that I am reading the lines from a file that I opened via `open(file, mode = 'rU')`

Comment: @mljrg: "Correctly" is complicated and depends on what concept of "character" you're dealing with. You might even need a third-party module, such as [`uniseg.graphemecluster`](http://uniseg-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/graphemecluster.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem. I just have to read the text file like this:

```
import codecs
with codecs.open(ficheiro, encoding='utf-8') as fin:
    for line in fin:
       ...  # then here line[5:7] will work correctly for "António" and "Antonio"
```

Thanks to Derek Dohler who wrote [Solving Unicode Problems in Python 2.7](https://www.azavea.com/blog/2014/03/24/solving-unicode-problems-in-python-2-7/)

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.7, strings and unicode strings are different objects. To declare a Unicode string literal, prefix it with a `u`:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = "António"
>>> len(s)
8
>>> s2 = u"António"
>>> len(s2)
7
>>> s[5:7]
'ni'
>>> s2[5:7]
u'io'
```

Comment: ok, but what if the string is a line read from a file? I cannot do that you suggest. Is there a way to convert the line to Unicode? This is not working when I open the file with this: `open(file, mode = 'rU')`

Comment: This may still produce unexpected results with combining characters. If that `ó` is a regular `o` and a combining acute accent, it'll still show up as two characters to `len` and slicing.

Comment: Yep, Unicode in Python 2.x is problematic. When working with file data, you need to know what its encoding was, and then decode from that encoding (on disk) into Unicode (in memory). The clearest explanation I've read is Ned Batchelder's 'Pragmatic Unicode' -- http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html